# what happens if you include three versions of jquery and have a script included in the middle that uses the jquery $ object

Tags: javascript, jquery, compilation, interpreter

I've come across a problem where I have multiple plugins conflicting over their version of jquery.  Now I have searched google, and I know that you should ultimately just use one version of jquery and update your code to that version of jquery.  However, out of curiousity, I'm interested in knowing what happens when you do the following:

```
<include latest jquery>
<include script that uses jquery>  <---and this jquery code is called back or triggered in some event handler function.. what happens then? what jquery $ version is used? the last jquery object that was added (the 'yet another version of jquery' )
<include some other version of jquery>
<include yet another version of jquery>
```

what version of jquery is used? and why? what exactly happens, how does the loading and execution of each script occur? does it just call the latest jquery's $ alias?  thank you for your help.

Comment: what makes you say they confilct? WHat versions are they using? Most versions are backward compatible back to 1.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will depend.  The scripts will be loaded and executed in order.  Any code that is executed immediately in your intermediate script will use the jQuery found in the top script.  Any code that is deferred till later (for instance function definitions that will be called by another script, or that are nested within event handlers) will use the final version loaded.

If that is not desired behavior you can use jQuery.noConflict(), although that may potentially involve modifying the plugins you're using to use the correct version.

Comment: this is indeed what happens, by testing it. i loaded three different jqueries, and had code that didnt use anything until it was fired, and they all printed the jquery version of the last version used.

Answer (score 6):

you can use jQuery.noConflict() to have multiple versions of jQuery.  Only one will use $.

for example

```
<script src='jquery-1.3.2.js'></script>
<script>
var jq132 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
<script src='jquery-1.4.2.js'></script>
<script>
var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict();
</script>
```

you can then use jq142 and jq132.  more details http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/

Answer (score 1):

When you include jQuery, it overrides the `jQuery` variable.  Thus, you actually can do what you are positing and it should work fine, even with `$`.

The reason not to do this is because it's not fun having to maintain multiple versions of software simultaneously, your client has to download multiple versions of jQuery, and you have a weird dependency on where to put some of your JS code that shouldn't be there.  Fix this problem at its source (i.e. use one version) as soon as you can.

In action: http://jsfiddle.net/AbAgu/

Comment: thank you for your reply. but what I dont understand is, what if the code in the script that uses jquery, is in a callback, that isnt called back until all later jquerys have been added, so it will just use the last definition of jquery that overrode everything else?

Comment: not quite accurate, load a version then load a plugin then load another version and plugin that was attached to first veersion of jQuery gets wiped out too. Fiddle demo has no plugins wit each instance

Comment: @Masu I don't understand your question

Comment: @charlietfl you wouldn't be able to use the new plugin call, but any bindings done by the plugin will still apply; the real problem would be if the plugin binds calls to removed methods

Comment: is more of a problem than that since a new `$.fn` gets created so first plugin method won't exist. See this happen all the time in wordpress sites where each person adds a new copy of jQuery when adding extensions

Comment: @charlietfl if the plugin's not compatible with the version of jQuery you load later, why would you need it to exist?

Comment: OK..my thoughts are all wrapped around normal use of `document.ready` . I looked closer at your fiddle and see you have code after each version. Likely help to explain that scripts won't work in head your way

Comment: @charlietfl it's generally recommended to put scripts in the body anyway

Comment: @ExplosionPills many don't and if code was wrapped in `ready` would end up using last loaded instance of jQuery, unless use `noConflict` which is likely easier to explain

Comment: OK, I take it back. Never tried it this way. A bit more hassle keeping code organized in different files but I see it does work now. http://jsfiddle.net/AbAgu/2/

Comment: @charlietfl just to clarify I 100% agree that it would be better to update to a single version, it's just that this is at least possible